# Git submodule workflow pull from upstream but push to own repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to keep a certain git repo in my repository as a submodule, lets say `git://somerepo` and

- take changes from upstream
- but not merging those changes back (because I don't have permissions)
- change the code that lives in `somerepo` repository and share changes with my teammates (not through upstream)

What is the most convenient workflow for this scenario (would be ideal if you share the order of commands you execute)?

### EDIT

`somerepo` also lives together with other code that is not shared with anyone, so it has to act as a separate repository within a repository, with push end pointing to my server and pull end pointing to upstream (if this is at all possible)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using a submodule but a separate repo instead:

`git remote set-url --push origin git://repourl`

so the push end is my server but fetch end is upstream.

You can check your current push/fetch configuration with

`git remote -v`